# PDO w/ MySQL - record not inserting with no errors

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, pdo, insert

First time I've had to use a posting on stackoverflow (largely due to the site itself)
but this has just gotten me.

Basic run down is I'm attempting to execute 2 stored procedures (table inserts) with PDO transactions.
The problem is consistent with every workaround I've tried:
They both execute, the first successfully enters a record, the second doesn't
No errors or exceptions (yes `$connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)` is set.

PHP Code Snippet:

```
$qry_add_address = "call egen_add_address(
    :district_id,
    :country_id,
    :city_id,
    :addr1,
    :addr2,
    :postal,
    :pobox,
    NULL,
    @newid
    )";
$db_link->beginTransaction();
try {               
    $db_add_addr = $db_link->prepare($qry_add_address);
    $db_add_addr->bindParam(':district_id',$address_inputs['district']['value'],    PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $db_add_addr->bindParam(':country_id',$address_inputs['country']['value'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $db_add_addr->bindParam(':city_id',$address_inputs['city']['value'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $db_add_addr->bindParam(':addr1',$address_inputs['addr1']['value'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $db_add_addr->bindParam(':addr2',$address_inputs['addr2']['value'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $db_add_addr->bindParam(':postal',$address_inputs['postal']['value'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $db_add_addr->bindParam(':pobox',$address_inputs['pobox']['value'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $db_add_addr->execute();                
$newid = $db_add_addr->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
$venue_inputs['address_id']['value'] = $newid[0];
$db_link->commit();
$db_add_addr->closeCursor();

} catch (PDOException $e) {
$logs['error'][] = 'call egen_add_address : '.$e->getMessage();
$db_link->rollBack();
}

/*
 * Add venue after address
 */     
$qry_add_venue = 
    "call egen_add_venue(
         :venue_type, 
         :address_id,
         :zone_id, 
         :name, 
         :description, 
         :img_file, 
         :phone_num, 
         :website, 
         1, 
         :max_capacity,
         '',
         @newid)";

$db_link->beginTransaction();
try {
    $db_add_venue = $db_link->prepare($qry_add_venue);
    $db_add_venue->bindParam(':venue_type', $venue_inputs['type_id']['value']);
    $db_add_venue->bindParam(':address_id', $venue_inputs['address_id']['value'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $db_add_venue->bindParam(':zone_id',$address_inputs['zone_id']['value'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $db_add_venue->bindParam(':name',$venue_inputs['name']['value'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $db_add_venue->bindParam(':description',$venue_inputs['description']['value'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $db_add_venue->bindParam(':img_file',$venue_inputs['img_file']['value'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $db_add_venue->bindParam(':phone_num',$venue_inputs['phone_num']['value'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $db_add_venue->bindParam(':website',$venue_inputs['website']['value'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $db_add_venue->bindParam(':max_capacity',$venue_inputs['max_capacity']['value'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $db_add_venue->execute();
    $logs['newid'] = $db_add_venue->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $db_link->commit();
    $db_add_venue->closeCursor();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $logs['error'][] = 'call egen_add_venue : '.$e->getMessage();
    $db_link->rollBack();
}
```

add Venue Stored Procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS egen_add_venue;
CREATE  PROCEDURE egen_add_venue (
    IN typid SMALLINT(3), 
    IN addid BIGINT(9),
    IN znid BIGINT(10),
    IN nm VARCHAR(90), 
    IN dscrptn TEXT, 
    IN imgfile VARCHAR(255), 
    IN phno VARCHAR(22), 
    IN url VARCHAR(2000),
    IN actv BIT(1),
    IN maxcap INT(7),
    IN tzone VARCHAR(20),
    OUT insertid BIGINT(9)
)
 BEGIN   
    INSERT INTO venue ( 
        `type_id`, `address_id`, `zone_id`, 
        `name_eng`, `description`, `img_file`, `phone_num`,
        `website`, `active`, `max_capacity`, `timezone`)
 VALUES (typid, addid, znid, 
            nm, dscrptn, imgfile, phno, 
            url, actv, maxcap, tzone);
 select last_insert_id() as insertid;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

mysql log file snippet:

```
123 Query     START TRANSACTION
123 Query     call egen_add_address(
    '36',
    '124'
    '18056'
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '0',
    NULL,
    @newid
    )
123 Query     START TRANSACTION
123 Query     call egen_add_venue(
    '1',
    '62',
    '97',
    'HOME',
    'sss',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    1,
    0,
    '',
    @newid)
```

When I copy and paste that log of the stored procedure call, it works and the record is inserted. The only thing I noticed is that is wraps my int params with single quotes, which didn't matter when attempting that into the mysql cli. I don't know how to stop it from doing this (I tried marked placeholders..using an array within the execute(), etc.)

I'm stumped, it's late, here's to hoping there's a dumb reason that I've missed.
Thank you

EDIT: I've echoed the execute, commit and closeCursor functions all returned 1.

Comment: *Update. This happens for me, even in newly created pages from scratch. My solution was to stop using stored procedures altogether. I've had too many problems with PHP whether it's mysqli or PDO executing multiple stored procedures in a script. Never have I've given up on a programming issue...it's shocking